# Qsort array of strings in descending order

Tags: c, sorting, arrays

To sort an array of strings in ascending order, I use:

```
int cmp(const void *p, const void *q) {
     char* const *pp = p;
     char* const *qq = q;
     return strcmp(*pp, *qq);
}
```

This will be then implemented into a qsort like so:

```
qsort(a, sizeof(a)(sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(a[0]), cmp);
```

How do you sort it in descending order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One quick and easy way to do this is to multiply the result of `strcmp()` by -1 before returning it.

```
int cmp(const void *p, const void *q) {
     char* const *pp = p;
     char* const *qq = q;
     return -strcmp(*pp, *qq);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `-1 * strcmp(…)` is a long-winded way of writing `-strcmp(…)`.  Another option is `strcmp(*qq, *pp)`, reversing the order of the arguments.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that's an excellent observation! I've amended the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just return the negative result (`-strcmp(*pp, *qq)`).

Comment: Or use `strcmp(*qq, *pp)`, reversing the order of the arguments.